# How to define received datatype, in backbone.js fetch()?

Tags: backbone.js, json, backbone-events

fetch data from server returns me json data as a **string** datatype rather than as **application/json** datatype, as a result the collection does not get refreshed.

I have tried giving the jquery.ajax option **contentType:"application/json"** to the fetch options, but still does not work.

how can i make it work? do i send a mimetype from the server? if so, how?

i am using json_encode on the data sent.

```
preloader.fetch({
        contentType:'application/json'
    });
```

preloader is an instance of my collection.

**edit:**
my template for a subview was not getting detected as i had kept it out of the masterview's **$el** element, corrected it, and now i am getting underscore.js error, that

**str is null in**

```
str.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')     //at line 913
```

is this because the backbone app is not taking it as a json object?

**Request headers**

```
Connection  close
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Thu, 12 Apr 2012 13:00:58 GMT
Server  Apache
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Vary    Accept-Encoding
```

**Response headers**
has the line

```
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
```

means it is a json, then what is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [add request header on backbone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081728/add-request-header-on-backbone)

Comment: its not the same, that guy wants to send data before making a fetch() request, i want to read the received data as a json.

Comment: I think you have a problem in the server side. It's not only the _contenttype_ but something else. Can you show us some how how the _request_ and the _response_ look like? for example: `$ curl http://localhost/myresource` and `$ curl -I http://localhost/myresource`.

Comment: Also.. don't add new questions to your already existing one. Focus in a concrete problem.

Comment: i just saw the response and request headers, everything looks alright there,

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow, i apologize if my format is not correct

Comment: @VipineshSingh it is the same -- how do you modify an ajax request that backbone makes.  The `$.ajax` method in jQuery can be told what datatype to coerce a response into.  Using `$.ajaxSetup` will allow you to set that parameter, and force the `$.ajax` command to coerce the response into a JSON, regardless of what your server is saying the data type is. [dataType section on $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: @VipineshSingh you have shown us the headers of the response.. but what about the **content of the response**. Is there there a proper JSON content?. Can you show us it somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the [contentType option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is for the request (your request).

Try `dataType:"json"`.

Comment: this is not necessary if you set proper headers for the server output "Content-Type: application/json"