# Not able to pass custom headers into Backbone's fetch

Tags: backbone.js

ers.

I am trying to implement my custom collection where I overwrite fetch method. Later I will use this collection to extend my Backbone collections.

```
var BaseCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    fetch: function (options) {
        options = options || {};

        if (!options.headers) {
            options.headers = {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization' : "Basic: user:password"
            };
        }

        options.reset = true;

        console.log('I am extended fetch method');

        return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
    }
});

var ShipsCollection = BaseCollection.extend({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/v1/ships',
    model: Ship
});
```

But when I call fetch for my collection I can not see headers were sent to the server:

```
var shipsCollection = new ShipsCollection();
shipsCollection.fetch();
```

[image]

***How can I extend fetch to be able send custome headers*** ? I do not want to [overwrite sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081728/add-request-header-on-backbone).

Comment: I might be mistaken, but your code seems to work as is http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/vc7p6wLm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was a AdBlock plugin. When I removed it everything went fine.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/vc7p6wLm/) shared by @nikoshr in comments, the code seems to work.

However, your code won't work in case `options.headers` exist. I suggest modifying the code as follows:

```
fetch: function(options) {
  options = options || {};
  var custom = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': "Basic: user:password"
  };
  options.headers = options.headers ? _.extend(options.headers, custom) : custom;

  options.reset = true;
  return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
}
```